# Need to send a pdf attachment from trigger when a update happed

Tags: trigger

I have created a trigger on my invoice object when a update happen I want to send a email from my trigger with a pdf attachment. But when I try to update my record I am getting an error.

> Error:Apex trigger TEST_on.sendEmailUpdate caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: TEST_on.sendEmailUpdate: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.VisualforceException: Getting content from within triggers is currently not supported.: Trigger.TEST_on.sendEmailUpdate: line 24, column 1

My trigger :

```
trigger sendEmailUpdate on Invoice__c (after update) {

public Invoice__c InvId = new Invoice__c (); 

if(trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isAfter){

    for(Invoice__c inv : trigger.New){
        if(InvName != null && InvName != '')
            InvName = InvName + inv.Name;
        else
            InvName = inv.Name;

    }

}
    //StreamingAPI

    PageReference pdf = Page.StreamingAPI;
    pdf.getParameters().put('id',(String)InvId.id);
    pdf.setRedirect(true);

    // Take the PDF content
    Blob b = pdf.getContent();

    // Create the email attachment
    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    efa.setFileName('attachment.pdf');
    efa.setBody(b);

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'emailID'};        
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    mail.setTemplateId('00X90000001gwM8');        
    mail.setSubject('Your invoice been updated ' );        
    mail.setSubject('Your invoice been updated ' );
    mail.setPlainTextBody('Invoice Name ' + InvName );
    mail.setHtmlBody('Invoice Name ' + InvName);     
    mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });    
}
```

Please help me out why this error is accrue. If it is possible to send attachment using MassEmailMessage from this same trigger. Then please let me limitation with MassEmailMessage.

Comment: You will have to do this inorder to send in PDF attachments from triggers . Create a site link ( login disabled site) . Set the site Home page as teh PDF generating page . From the trigger , call in a batch and in the batch , use the SINGLE email messaging class to send PDF attachments . Just make sure you set the code this way : mail.setBody(give the site link here ). It will become an attachment by itself . By this way , you can send in PDF attachments using a trigger by an indirect way .Let me know if you need any help on the same.Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

**Issue:**

1. You are using "PageReference" in trigger. Getting content from page in Trigger code  is not allowed.
2. Because this is trigger, Trigger is fire base on record insert/update/delete.
3. Getting content is taking some time so when user update/create a record through UI it take more time to execute trigger.

**Solution:**

1. You just need to create one future method into trigger with **"callout"**
   as **"True"**.
2. So, When trigger is fired, Salesforce is not waiting for that future method completion.

**Updated your Code:**

```
trigger sendEmailUpdate on Invoice__c (after update) {

public Invoice__c InvId = new Invoice__c ();

if(trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isAfter){

for(Invoice__c inv : trigger.New){
    if(InvName != null && InvName != '')
        InvName = InvName + inv.Name;
    else
        InvName = inv.Name;

}

}

//StreamingAPI
attachPDFInEmail(attachPDFInEmail);

}

@future(callout = true)
private static void attachPDFInEmail(String InvName){
    PageReference pdf = Page.StreamingAPI;
    pdf.getParameters().put('id',(String)InvId.id);
    pdf.setRedirect(true);

    // Take the PDF content
    Blob b = pdf.getContent();

    // Create the email attachment
    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    efa.setFileName('attachment.pdf');
    efa.setBody(b);

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'emailID'};        
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    mail.setTemplateId('00X90000001gwM8');        
    mail.setSubject('Your invoice been updated ' );        
    mail.setSubject('Your invoice been updated ' );
    mail.setPlainTextBody('Invoice Name ' + InvName );
    mail.setHtmlBody('Invoice Name ' + InvName);     
    mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use @future(callout=true) to generate pdf from visualforce

Comment: Can you expand on this? It doesn't really help on it's own with no explanation!