# I have written test class for email sending functionality class trying to cover code up to 100% but covered 80% only?

Tags: unit-test

```
public class CheckboxEmail {
public boolean cbox{set;get;}
public String emailTo {get; set;}
    public String emailBody {get; set;}
    public String response {get; set;}

    public PageReference sendEmail(){
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {emailTo});
        mail.setReplyTo('noreply@yourcompany.com');
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Your Company Name');
        mail.setSubject('Test Email From Force.com Sites');
        mail.setPlainTextBody(emailBody);
        try{

            Messaging.SendEmailResult[] resultMail = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

            if(resultMail[0].isSuccess() && cbox==true)       
               // response = 'ok sent Succesfully!';
                 ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'ok Email sent Succesfully!'));
            else if(cbox==false){
             ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'Please Make Checkbox True'));
                //response = resultMail[0].getErrors().get(0).getMessage();
            }

        }catch(System.EmailException ex){
            response = ex.getMessage();
        }   
        return null;
    }

}
```

Test Class:

```
@istest
public class CheckboxEmail_Test{
static testmethod void CheckboxEmail_Test()
{
CheckboxEmail ce=new CheckboxEmail();
ce.sendEmail();
System.assertEquals(true, ce.cbox); 
}
static testmethod void CheckboxEmail_Test1()
{
CheckboxEmail ce1=new CheckboxEmail();
ce1.sendEmail();
System.assertEquals(false, ce1.cbox); 
}
}
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: The two answers to this question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/82615/2602 will give you ideas of how to resolve this; when I had this issue, I used the second approach given in the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
@istest
public class CheckboxEmail_Test{

    static testmethod void CheckboxEmail_Test_cbox_true() {
        CheckboxEmail ce=new CheckboxEmail();
        ce.emailTo = 'foo@example.com';
        ce.emailBody = 'hello, world!';
        ce.response = 'response';
        ce.cbox = true;
        ce.sendEmail();
        System.assertEquals(true, ce.cbox); 
    }

    static testmethod void CheckboxEmail_Test_cbox_false() {
        CheckboxEmail ce =new CheckboxEmail();
        ce.emailTo = 'foo@example.com';
        ce.emailBody = 'hello, world!';
        ce.response = 'response';
        ce.cbox = false;
        ce.sendEmail();
        System.assertEquals(false, ce.cbox); 
    }

    static testmethod void CheckboxEmail_Test_throw_exception() {
        CheckboxEmail ce =new CheckboxEmail();
        ce.sendEmail();
        System.assertEquals(null, ce.cbox); 
    }
}
```

You need to set values to member variables of `CheckboxEmail`.
And, both of your original tests throw System.EmailException because you don't set "to" and "body" of Email.