# Visualforce Attachment with email on trigger fire

Tags: visualforce, trigger, email, attachment

I have a trigger which fires an email on my custom object.
I want a visualforce page as a attachment to that  email.
I tried but it is not working.
Please help me out.

Here is my trigger.

```
trigger EmailOnApprovedRecord on Quote__c (before update) {

public boolean EmailStatus;
Quote__c Quote = [select id, PR_Number__c, RFQ_Status__c,RFQ_Supplier__r.name, RFQ_Supplier__c from Quote__c limit 1];

ProcessInstance[] PI = [Select CompletedDate, LastActorId, ProcessDefinitionId, Status, TargetObjectId,(SELECT Id, StepStatus, Comments FROM StepsAndWorkitems)  from  ProcessInstance where TargetObjectId ='a002800000BbNm8' limit 1];
system.debug('***************'+PI);
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

Map<Id,Quote__c> o = new Map<Id,Quote__c>();
o = trigger.oldMap;

For(Quote__c Q: trigger.new){
    Quote__c old = new Quote__c();
    old = o.get(Q.Id);
IF (trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isBefore){
    IF( PI.size()>0 && Q.RFQ_Status__c == 'Approved' ){
        IF(Q.RFQ_Status__c !=old.RFQ_Status__c  && PI[0].Status == 'Approved') {
             EmailStatus = TRUE;
        }
        IF( EmailStatus == True && (Q.RFQ_Status__c != 'Pending' || Q.RFQ_Status__c != 'Submitted' || Q.RFQ_Status__c != 'Submitted To Supplier ' || Q.RFQ_Status__c != 'Rejected') ){
           // PageReference pdf =  Page.quotePDF;
           // pdf.getParameters().put('id',(String)q.id); 
           // pdf.setRedirect(true);

          //  Blob b = pdf.getContent();

           // Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
           // efa.setFileName('QuotePDF.pdf');
           // efa.setBody(b);
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            system.debug('******QUOTE ID-----'+Quote.id+'********Quote PR No. ------'+quote.PR_Number__c+'********Quote Supplier------'+quote.RFQ_Supplier__c );
            mail.setToAddresses(new String[]{'vrushabh.katariya@zamilindustrial.com'});
            String body ='<html><body> Dear,<br><br> submitted PR-'+Quote.PR_Number__c+ ' to '+Quote.RFQ_Supplier__r.name + '  with SLA clock <br><br> Thanks, <br><br> ZIS Support</body></html>';
            mail.setHtmlBody(body);
            mail.setSubject('_PR-'+Quote.PR_Number__c);
          //  mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});

            emails.add(mail); 
            Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
            EmailStatus =False;
        }


    }
}  
}
```

}

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: My above code is not giving any error. I want to attach my visualforce page with an email when trigger gets fired.

Comment: It is sending an email as i want. But I am unable to attach visualforce page along with email.

Comment: Since the lines which gets the PDF from Visualforce page and attaching it as attachment to email is commented, you are not getting the email with attachments. Can you try by uncommenting those lines?

Comment: Actually the moment I uncomment those lines, It start giving me an error

Comment: What error you are getting? Is it related to callouts?

Comment: Following error I get **EmailOnApprovedRecord: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.VisualforceException: Getting content from within triggers is currently not supported**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28859/discussion-between-vigneshwaran-g-and-sfdcpro).

Comment: This link has a potential answer to your problem. I didnt try it though!  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53409/need-to-send-a-pdf-attachment-from-trigger-when-a-update-happed